# Could not locate usable POSIX Threads in Centos 7

Tags: c, unix, pthreads, centos7

I run QuickFile to build my application in centos7.

Centos 7 was clean Installed.

but I saw these messages.

how to solve this problem..?

### Thank you

```
checking for pthread_create in default libraries... no

checking for pthread link with -kthread... no

checking for pthread link with -pthread... no

checking for pthread link with -pthreads... no

checking for pthread link with -mthreads... no

checking for pthread link with -thread... no

checking for pthread link with -lpthread -lmach -lexc -lc_r... no

checking for pthread link with -lpthread -lmach -lexc... no

checking for pthread link with -lpthread -Wl,-woff,85... no

checking for pthread link with -lpthread... no

checking for pthread link with -lc_r... no

checking for pthread link with -threads... no

checking for pthread link with -lpthreads -lmach -lexc -lc_r... no

checking for pthread link with -lpthreads -lmach -lexc... no

checking for pthread link with -lpthreads -lexc... no

checking for pthread link with -lpthreads... no

configure: error: could not locate usable POSIX Threads
```

Comment: Guess you're missing the headers and such for pthreads, i.e. you need to install some package like libpthread-dev (I do not know the exact name)

Answer (score 2):

> how to solve this problem

You need to install `glibc-devel` package.